# Sublime Text 3 Hides scrollbars

Tags: sublimetext3

I would prefer to always see the scroll-bars in Sublime Text 3.  The current behavior is for them to remain hidden until you start scrolling.  Is there a setting I can change to make it behave this way?  Is it part of the theme?  Right now I am making the scroll-bars larger by modifying my theme ([Cyanide](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Cyanide))... I have

```
// in Cyanide.sublime-theme
[
    {
        "class": "scroll_bar_control",
        "attributes": ["horizontal"],
        "content_margin": [3, 4] //makes horiz scrollbar taller
    },
    {
        "class": "scroll_bar_control",
        "content_margin": [1, 3] //makes vert scrollbar taller
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm the creator of the Cyanide theme, if you still have issue with this, feel free to contact me. I could make a new setting inside the theme :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is under the `overlay_scroll_bars` setting. Overlaid scroll bars disappear when not active, so update your user preferences with the following:

```
"overlay_scroll_bars": "disabled"
```

Comment: I tried this.  It changed the colour and size of my scrollbars (no longer using the theme?), but they still kept disappearing.

Comment: PS: and to hide the scrollbars: `"overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled"`

Comment: You need to restart sublime to this take effect.

Comment: Update; final 3.0 build 3143 Sublime text release finally fixed the color scheme in my case so that I am actually able to see the scrollbars vs just have them present.

Comment: It's a shame that I cannot always show only the horizontal but hide the vertical.

Answer (score 4):

I was also having trouble with this. After looking at several references on stack overflow and elsewhere, I actually found a very elegant solution. I am using the Seti_UI theme, so other themes may be a bit different, but they should be close. First, go to the **Preferences** menu and choose **Browse Packages...** . Look for the name of the theme you are using. For me, I had to go to the **Seti_UI** folder and open **Seti.sublime-theme** in Sublime. You want to find information about your *scroll pucks* like in my code sample below. It's the **"layer0.tint":[44,62,78],** that needs changing. You increase the RGB values to your heart's content. Repeat for other *pucks* of interest. Worked great for me. Hope it does for others.

```
 // Standard vertical scroll puck
{
    "class": "puck_control",
    "layer0.tint":[44,62,78],
    "layer0.opacity": { "target": 1.0, "speed": 10.0, "interpolation": "smoothstep" },
    "layer0.inner_margin": 0,
    "content_margin": [3,0],
    "blur": false
},
```

Comment: give this man a beer! I like a lot Seti theme, but the horizontal scroll bar was so hard to hold and drag... no more! Changed the tint to the rgb I desired (added 100 to each value and now is clearly visible), and increased the second parameter of content_margin to 10 (it was 3), so now I have a horizontal scroll bar that is big and easy to see and hold!

And reference documentation: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#texture_tinting_properties

Answer (score 2):

add the following to theme user override file

```
// in Cyanide.sublime-theme
[
    {
        "class": "scroll_area_control",
        "overlay": false
    }
]
```

Comment: On OSX , this did not work for me, but the disable, above, did.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen in Sublime Text only or are using Mac OS X with the default scrollbar behaviour? In the latter case you can force the scrollbars to always show in the [General preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18803).

Comment: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: mac osx with scrollbars always on , sublime has this problem @idleberg . Sublimetext does not respect my settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
"overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the minimap viewport in your Preferences settings - user:

```
"always_show_minimap_viewport": true
```

From now on you will always see the scroll bar. And if you want to see a Border around the minimap add in the Package Theme you are using:

```
<key>minimapBorder</key>
<string>#999999</string>
```