# how to make scroll bar indicator more clear and easy to see?

Tags: sublimetext3

Using Submine test 3, build 3083 on windows 7.
Currently using Dawn.tm theme, selected from `Preferences`->`Color themes`

The only problem is that the little indicator on the side bar that one uses to scroll down and up the page is so hard to see. It is dark gray and the scroll bar itself is black.

Could someone please show simple step by step how to make the indicator more clear? May be color it while and have the bar remain black, so it is easier to spot?  Here is screen shot on my current layout:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For reference, I have been trying to use what is giving in [this question](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/116003-make-the-scrollbar-markerindicator-more-visible/), but I keep getting an error when I paste the code shown there in my `Preferences.sublime-settings`. I get syntax error. But I am giving the above link in case it helps.

My current `Preferences.sublime-settings` is the following

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Dawn.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 12,
    "highlight_line": false,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
    "rulers":
    [
        74
    ],
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "use_tab_stops": false,
    "word_wrap": false,
    "bold_folder_labels": true
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your user folder you can override the themes properties you want. In this case there is a minor problem as the scrollbar texture (the image that contains the scrollbar with the top and bottom semicircles) is quite dark, so although you modify the tint you can't get a light color similar to white unless you change that texture (image).

So the solution I pruposse is to create two new images (horizontal and vertical scrollbar) that are lighter, set it in the theme preference overrides and then (optionally) set the tint color you want.

### Step by step tutorial

1. Locate your sublime *User* folder (Packages/User). The Packages folder can be opened using the sublime menu *Preferences>Browse Packages*, inside is located the *User* folder.
2. Inside *User* folder create a directory called *theme_override*. We are going to place here all the files and settings of our theme that we want to override.
3. Inside this folder (*theme_override*) put this two images and name them *[scroll_puck.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eExe.png)*[image: Vertical scrollbar] and *[scroll_puck_horiz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4rV2.png)*[image: Horizontal scrollbar].
4. Inside *theme_override*, create a file with the name of your theme. If you are using the default theme the file should be named *Default.sublime-theme*. If you are not using the default theme you can see the name of the theme you are using in *Settings>Preferences>theme*, and then create a file with that name (for example *Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme*) inside *theme_override*
   Inside this new file place the following content:

   ```
   [    
       // More visible scrollbar
       {
           "class": "puck_control",
           "layer0.texture": "User/theme_override/scroll_puck.png",
           // Optional: set to your desired RGB color
           "layer0.tint": [40, 170, 250],
           "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
           "layer1.opacity": 0.0,
           "layer0.inner_margin": 2
       },
       {
           "class": "puck_control",
           "attributes": ["horizontal"],
           "layer0.texture": "User/theme_override/scroll_puck_horiz.png"
       }
   ]
   ```
5. Restart sublime text
6. Optional modify RGB color (no need to restart again).

**EDIT**: this is the result

[image: Result]

**EDIT**: added basic info for people that are not using the default theme.

**Note: if you are not using the default theme** the results might change depending on the values that your theme overrides. If you want to know what values your theme is using, and you want to customize them, you can see them inside the *.sublime-package file* of your theme. For example, if you are using *Material Theme* open *Material Theme.sublime-package* (this is just a zip file) and inside there will be a file called *Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme*, you should not modify this file, but you can customize/override whatever you want using the file we have created in step 4.

Comment: I can't try your instructions. I am stuck on first step. I click on `Preferences>Browse Packages` and nothing happens. Nothing opens.  I am using version 3, build 3083. I also do it from `Tools`->`Command palette`->`Preferences: Browse packages` and nothing happens. Windows remains blank.   Why are files names have spaces in them? This is really very bad design for this editor to have its configuration text file names with spaces in file name itself. I can't believe such advanced editor will do this.

Comment: Inside linux user folder usually is located at /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User and in windows C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User

Comment: I know where the folder is, but you wrote `Packages folder should be opened`. So you want me to just create a directory called `Theme - Default` with the dash and the spaces as is? and  create a file called `Default.sublime-theme` inside the new directory? ok, will do that. I can create the directory myself outside of the editor.

Comment: Create the folder inside `Packages/User` . So it will be `Packages/User/Theme - Default` . I give it this name because the default package is called `Theme - Default.sublime-package`

Comment: Thanks. I just did and it worked. I just need to make the png images, but I already see difference. Here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hubTQ.png) . (ps. someone should tell the folks who wrote this editor to get rid of all the spaces from the file names. Use underscore instead) Using spaces in file names is terrible idea for many reasons and it reflects bad impression on the application.

Comment: Something went wrong as that happens when sublime doesn't find the image. This is the [result](http://i.imgur.com/AneyyQN.png) I get. You right thats a bad practice, you can really give the folder the name you want but if you modify it you'll have to modify it also in the content of Default.sublime-theme file inside the folder. If the problem isn't solved yet please open a chat so we can find out what is happening.

Comment: After I copied the images you have there, now it looks like this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fda3M.png)  so it is ok now. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want you should be able to change the tint value to change the color.

Comment: Still works in ST 3 build 3114 (year 2016). Also when theme is not the initial default one but one of other build in ones. Thanks.

Comment: I think I'll actually buy Sublime now since I can see their scrollbar.. lol thanks @sergioFC

Comment: Thanks, it works for me as well for sublime build 3126. One trick I encountered, pls check whether you use the default theme. I updated to use a different theme in the Preferences.sublime-setting - User before. So it dose not work at first. After commenting it out and use the default theme, then it works.

Comment: @sergioFC, thanks for your reply. I created a new folder with "Default" replaced with the theme name I use, also modified the path in the file "custome_theme_name.sublime-theme", but it dose not work

Comment: @sergioFC, hi, it is: "theme": "Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme".

Comment: @zhihong I've downloaded the theme and edited the question to add info for people that are not using the default theme. You'll see that the bar size looks a bit bigger than the bar with the default theme, but you still can customize the color. By the way, sorry for the long delay. I'll soon remove my last comments in order to keep this post a bit cleaner. If you have any problem or question feel free to ask me anything.

Comment: absolutely crazy difficult to do, but the steps work - many thanks from 2019

Answer (score 4):

This works nicely. However, the problem is that the "puck" only appears when you use the mouse to scroll up or down. When I try to grab the puck to scroll right, it disappears. We need a stable scrollbar as in most interfaces.
This adjustment makes the scrollbars more stable:

```
{
    "class": "puck_control",
    "layer0.texture": "User/Theme - Default/vertical_white_scrollbar.png",
    "content_margin": [3, 4], //makes horiz scrollbar taller
    // Adjust RGB color. Optional: comment the following line (or set 255,255,255) to not modify image color
    "layer0.tint": [200, 170, 250]
},
{
    "class": "puck_control",
    "attributes": ["horizontal"],
    "content_margin": [3, 4], //makes horiz scrollbar taller
    "layer0.texture": "User/Theme - Default/horizontal_white_scrollbar.png"

}
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected"]}],
    //"fg": [30,30,30],
    "fg": [255,131,0] //change highlighted tab color
}
```

Derived from: [Sublime Text 3 Hides scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754371/sublime-text-3-hides-scrollbars)

Answer (score 4):

What I do is change the color of the "mini map" to make the scroll control much more visible, as opposed to a lot of other solutions that recommend changing the color of the scrollbars themselves.

[image: changing sublime mini map]

Here are some fantastic instructions that personally greatly helped me out: https://github.com/kujiy/how-to-change-sublime-minimap-color

You can create a theme override in your Sublime installation folder under Packages/User by creating a new directory named "theme_override" then creating a file named "*your-theme-name*.sublime-theme" and saving it with something like this:

```
[
    {
        "class": "minimap_control",
        "settings": ["always_show_minimap_viewport"],
        "viewport_color": [255, 255, 255],
        "viewport_opacity": 0.15,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize you sublime text in a better way. Install a package through package control name ***Seti_UI***. and customize your sublime. You can customize all of the Interface using ***Seti_UI***. I customized my Sublime Text and have the following settings.

You can do it by your own.
Go to -> ***Preferences*** -> ***Settings*** -> ***User defined settings*** and after installing the above mentioned Package.

```
"theme": "Seti.sublime-theme",
"caret_extra_width": 2,                 //  to have a wider/thicker caret
"caret_extra_bottom": 3,                //  to make the caret = to the line height (the theme currently support 0,3,5)
"caret_extra_top": 3,
"highlight_line": true,
"Seti_tabs_small": true,
"Seti_no_under_bar":true,
"Seti_yellow_tabclose": true,
"Seti_indigo_scrollbar": true,
"Seti_SB_med": true,
"Seti_sb_big_padding": true,
"Seti_bold_slctdfile_labels": true,
"Seti_sidebar_font_size_14": true,
"Seti_yellow_map": true,
"Seti_accent_lime": true,
"Seti_ClosedFolder_anim": true,
"Seti_teal_statusbar": true,
"Seti_panel_nrml": true,
"Seti_dark_fold_button": true,
"Seti_ClosedFolder_dots": true,
"Seti_sidebar_font_Fira": true,
"Seti_sidebar_font_Hack": true,
"Seti_bold_heading":true,              // make heading font in bold
"Seti_no_heading":true,                // remove the "folder,group 1,etc.."
"Seti_top_heading_big":true,           // sidebar top header img big
"Seti_top_heading_small":true,         // sidebar top header img small
"Seti_top_heading_anim" :true,          // sidebar top header img animate on hover
"Seti_alt_tree_row":true,
```